# How to use AspectHistogramContainer in ebay Finding API?

Tags: java, ebay-api

I am a newbie trying to write a program to get a database of dress images from eBay using the finding API. I am programming in Java and using Windows 7 OS. After taking the keyword to be searched for from the user, I used the FindItemsAdvanced call for getting the list of products under that category. I want to get the attributes of each of those items like colour, sleeve length, etc. For this, I used AspectHistogramContainer to get the aspects and the values.  The code snippet is below:

```
AspectHistogramContainer aspectContainer=new AspectHistogramContainer();
aspectContainer=advanceResponse.getAspectHistogramContainer();
aspectContainer.setDomainDisplayName(keywords);
aspectContainer.setDomainName(keywords);            
List<Aspect> aspectList=aspectContainer.getAspect();
for(Aspect aspect:aspectList)
{               
    System.out.println(aspect.getName());
    List<AspectValueHistogram> aspectValueList= aspect.getValueHistogram();
    for(AspectValueHistogram aspectValue:aspectValueList)
    {
        System.out.println(aspectValue.getValueName());
        }
}
```

advanceResponse is the FindItemsAdvancedResponse Object.

But the AspectHistogramContainer is always only null, i.e the items have no aspects. I gave only leaf categories as input as required by AspectHistogramContainer. I have tried all avenues but cant find the reason.Could somebody please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! I had to set the category Id for the GetHistogramRequest object and then use that object to get the AspectHistogramContainer. The code snippet is below:

```
GetHistogramsRequest abcd = new GetHistogramsRequest();
abcd.setCategoryId(CatID.toString());
GetHistogramsResponse bb = port.getHistograms(abcd);
advanceResponse.setAspectHistogramContainer(bb.getAspectHistogramContainer());
AspectHistogramContainer aspectContainer=new AspectHistogramContainer();
aspectContainer=advanceResponse.getAspectHistogramContainer();
aspectContainer.setDomainDisplayName(keywords);
aspectContainer.setDomainName(keywords);            
List<Aspect> aspectList=aspectContainer.getAspect();
for(Aspect aspect:aspectList)
{               
    System.out.println(aspect.getName());
    List<AspectValueHistogram> aspectValueList= aspect.getValueHistogram();
    for(AspectValueHistogram aspectValue:aspectValueList)
    {
        System.out.println(aspectValue.getValueName());
        }
}
```

CatId is the categoryId and advanceResponse is the FindItemsByAdvanceRequestObject.But this still only gives the aspects under each category. To get the specific aspect of each item under that category, aspect filter should be used. I am not sure of how to initalise the aspect values for each aspect in the aspect filter and how to associate it with a response object. Any ideas?